# Indent in Python makes Variable unaccessable

Tags: python

So I have the selfmade class `element` and I want to create a function, that takes in keyword-arguments which get passed into the constructor of `element`

It looks like this:

```
class element:
    def __init__(self, name="element", count=1):
        self.name = name
        self.count = count

def create_element(**kwargs):
    try:
        el = element(**kwargs)
    except TypeError:
        print("You chose arguments which no element has")
    return el
```

My problem is not that I want a completely different code, but rather to fix the problem I have when I want to return `el` of the method `create_element`. If I run this code now, I have a `UnboundLocalError`, which tells me, that I am accessing a variable before initialing it.

I have tried a `finally` block, but it had the same result.
I see why this is but I don't have a solution.

Comment: You're missing the `def`keyword  before your `__init__` That is, your code should say `def __init__(self, name = "element", count =1):`

Comment: @Toothpick Anemone thanks, just a typing mistake... I will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define `el` with a default value outside the `try`:

```py
class element:
    def __init__(self, name="element", count=1):
        self.name = name
        self.count = count

def create_element(**kwargs):
    el = None
    try:
        el = element(**kwargs)
    except TypeError:
        print("You chose arguments which no element has")
    finally:
        return el
```

Comment: Yeah but what do I do when I want some other Code outside the try-block which doesn't have to be tried? Of course I thought about that but I wanted an other answer, sorry

Comment: Thanks, thats the answer I was looking for! I feel so dumb that I couldn't see this on my own, it's so obvious!

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the return value to some default value ***before*** executing the `try` block:

```
el = None # initialize return value to default "None"
try:
    el = element(**kwargs)
except TypeError:
    print("You chose arguments which no element has")
return el
```

Alternatively, move the return statement inside of the try-block

```
try:
    el = element(**kwargs)
    return el
except TypeError:
    print("You chose arguments which no element has")
```

Answer (score -1):

This is why [finally](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_finally.asp) exists in python.

```
def create_element(**kwargs):
    el = None
    try:
        el = element(**kwargs)
    except TypeError:
        print("You chose arguments which no element has")
    finally:
        return el
```

Comment: here you'd still get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'el' referenced before assignment`

Comment: If a type error occurs, then `el` never gets assigned to. `el` does not exist. Therefore, the finally block will raise an exception. You can't return `el` because there is no such thing.